# Making antd's Sider responsive

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, antd

I am attempting to implement a responsive app with antd.
One of the things I have is a `Sider` menu as my main navigation. One of the things I would like to do is that on small screens this sider be collapsed (as the hamburguer icon preferrably). I have no idea how to even start this. My component with the sidebar looks something like this:

```
class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Layout>
        <Sider width={200} collapsedWidth={500}>
          <Menu
            mode="inline"
            defaultSelectedKeys={['1']}
            defaultOpenKeys={['sub1']}
            style={{ height: '100%' }}
          >
              <Menu.Item key="1">option1</Menu.Item>
              <Menu.Item key="2">option2</Menu.Item>
              <Menu.Item key="3">option3</Menu.Item>
              <Menu.Item key="4">option4</Menu.Item>
          </Menu>
        </Sider>
        </Layout>
    );
  }
}
```

I should probably also point out that from the [Layout docs](https://ant.design/components/layout/), the following is said:

> Note: You can get a responsive layout by setting breakpoint, the Sider will collapse to the width of collapsedWidth when window width is below the breakpoint. And a special trigger will appear if the collapsedWidth is set to 0.

However I could not get this to work. Perhaps I misunderstand it.

Unfortunately I am not able to embed my sample app in the editor here, so I [here is my working sample app](https://codesandbox.io/embed/antdesign-iww3j). All I would like to do is collapse my `Sider` navbar into a hamburguer icon or even an arrow like icon on small screens. Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `collapsible` sider [official example](https://codesandbox.io/s/t8cw7).

From here you can choose whatever width \ icons you need based on state.

Also, you have a [good example](https://preview.pro.ant.design/dashboard/analysis) of `antd` components, especially a sidebar with the hamburger icon.